# Multiple words on php form

Tags: php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['discount'] == 'text1')
    echo "Discount Applied!";
else
    header('Location:fifapack.html');
?>
```

I want to be able to add more words after text 1 and not just one valid word.

```
<div id="dicount">
        <form action=discounts.php method=post>
        <center>Discount Code:<input type=text name=discount>
        <input type=submit value=Apply>
        </center>
    </div>
```

This is my html.

Comment: what you want to say explain clearly

Comment: Is this what u r asking for..

if ($_POST['discount'] == 'text1' || $_POST['discount'] == 'text2' || $_POST['discount'] == 'text3')

Comment: As you might have seen, you have gotten 3 completely different answers. Maybe you should be more clear about what you want to achieve.

Comment: The only 'discount' that works in the form is text1. I want to have more then just one piece of text working

Answer (score 0):

You can send several discounts this way:

```
<div id="dicount">
    <form action=discounts.php method=post>
    <center>Discount Code:<input type="text" name="discount[]">
    <center>Discount Code:<input type="text" name="discount[]">
    <center>Discount Code:<input type="text" name="discount[]">
    <center>Discount Code:<input type="text" name="discount[]">
    <input type=submit value=Apply>
    </center>
</div>
```

And in your php:

```
$b = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'discount', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

if($b) {
    // Do whatever you like with the array of discounts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine if text1 is in your POST, you can simply use:

```
if (strpos($_POST['discount'], 'text1')) {
... 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to validate $_POST['discount'] against more
words?

```
<?php


if (($_POST['discount'] == 'text1') or ($_POST['discount'] == 'whatever')) {
    echo "Discount Applied!";
}
else {
    header('Location:fifapack.html');
}


?>
```